# Receive text, make a phone call and run in background indefinitely

Tags: android

Situation: My apartment building has a closed parking lot with a gate that opens upon calling a specific number (only some numbers can open the gate, including mine).

My request: I am trying to make an application (for my own phone), which would read an incoming SMS with a specific keyword, and then call the number, which opens the gate. Furthermore, this app should work while it is not in foreground (either by running in background or maybe intent-filters?).

Is it at all possible, and how do I achieve this?

My current "solution" is provided below, but it does not work (keep in mind I'm a complete beginner).

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SmsListener listener = new SmsListener();
    String msgBody = listener.getMsgBody();

    if (msgBody.contains("keyword")) {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("number"));

        startActivity(callIntent);

    }

}
```

}

SmsListener class:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

private SharedPreferences preferences;
String msgBody = "";

public String getMsgBody(){

    return msgBody;

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        if (bundle != null){
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                    Toast.makeText(context, msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have no idea if the above code is at least partially correct, any help would be appreciated.

When I send a text from another phone, the toast I wrote does not appear, meaning that the code doesn't even run probably.

My manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" /> // Error saying that only system apps can use this permission

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What is the issue u r facing with this code?

Comment: If you want to listen to messages even when the app is not used in foreground. You need a service not an activity

Comment: This code is what i managed to glue up from other posts, but it does not work as intended. I don't really know where to go from here, hence the post @NoumanGhaffar

Comment: `BROADCAST_SMS` is not a permission you can hold, so that's why you get an error. You don't need to hold that one, though. (It should be in a `permission` attribute on the Receiver, but it won't break your app if it's not for now.) `CALL_PHONE` and `RECEIVE_SMS` are both dangerous permissions, so you need to request them at runtime if you're on Marshmallow, and your `targetSdkVersion` is 23+. If you don't have the `RECEIVE_SMS`, you just won't get that broadcast, so it'll look like nothing's happening.

Comment: I've added the changes, but it's still not working. I don't know if this is the correct procedure to achieve what I am looking for..

Comment: What changes, exactly? Are you successfully requesting the permissions at runtime? Or, alternatively, did you drop your `targetSdkVersion` to 22? If you did that, you still have to launch your `MainActivity` at least once after installation before that Receiver will work. Are you seeing the `Toast` in the Receiver? (You should use log prints instead for debugging.) Are you testing on a device that has other restrictions for apps receiving SMS? Beyond that, I would mention that you don't start `MainActivity` from the Receiver, and you're not handling `msgBody` correctly, so it'll be null there.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much for your help! I made it work.